# How do I rename a table in SQL Server Compact Edition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-ce

I've designed my SQL CE tables using the built-in designer in VS2008. I chose the wrong names for a couple. I am now completely stuck trying to find a way to rename them.

I am refusing to believe that such a feature could have been "forgotten". How do I rename an existing table using the VS2008 designer, or a free stand-alone app?

Comment: Using the SQL Server Compact Toolbox for VS this can be done: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2007/08/hidden-gem-rename-table.html
as answer to this later question shows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854661/how-to-rename-a-table-in-the-sql-server-compact-edition

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not sure about doing it via VS2008, but you can use `sp_rename`: Changes the name of a user table in the current database. Currently, sp_rename support in SQL Server Compact 3.5 is limited to tables.

```
sp_rename [ @objname = ] 'object_name', 
          [ @newname = ] 'new_name' 
          [ , [ @objtype = ] 'object_type' ]
```

Comment: Hey, that's a great third party app! Thanks for the tip! :-) (It has a 30 day trial version)

Answer (score 18):

To rename the table oldtable to newtable:

```
sp_rename 'oldtablename', 'newtablename';
```

Comment: With single quotes around table names.