# How to rename a table in the sql server compact edition

Tags: sql, sql-server, compact-database

I'm new to SQL Server Compact edition. I'm using Compact edition 3.5. I tried renaming the table. But, I couldn't do that through the following query.

> alter table tablename to newname

Plz, someone help me.........

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
sp_rename '[OldTableName]' , '[NewTableName]'
```

Check links below for more information

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/26/sql-server-how-to-rename-a-column-name-or-table-name/

http://erikej.blogspot.com/2007/08/hidden-gem-rename-table.html

Good Luck!

**UPDATE**

Here you can find a similar question

[How do I rename a table in SQL Server Compact Edition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528805/how-do-i-rename-a-table-in-sql-server-compact-edition)

You can try this tool

http://www.primeworks-mobile.com/

or try this in visual studio

```
conn.Open();
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("sp_rename 'oldTable', 'newTable' ", conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks. But, it is showing the error as cannot parse the query. I'm using visual studio 2008. I don't have front end to work with sql server 2008. . .

Answer (score 7):

In Visual Studio:

1. Right click on database file in Database Explorer
2. Select new query
3. Type: sp_rename 'oldName' , 'newName'
4. Press Ctrl+R key
5. Finish

Answer (score 0):

This works in Visual Studio 2010 Express:

**Select Tables** in the database explorer and right-click to get the contextual menu

Select **New Request**, this will open a new page in which you can type any sql request to your database, so you can now type something like

> sp_rename 'oldname', 'newname'

Right-click again in this window and select **Execute SQL** in the menu, that's it!

Don't forget to refresh the database explorer view to see the new name

Answer (score -3):

Please copy this table and data to new table and then delete old table. Same logic with rename.

```
insert into New_TableName
select *
from Old_TableName
```